# .c.s: in linux-0.11 makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I have tried to `build linux-0.11`. 
And I found that the makefile in `linux-0.11` contains :

```
.c.s:
@$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -S -o $*.s $<
.s.o:
@$(AS) -o $*.o $<
.c.o:
@$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $*.o $<
```

Could anyone tell me that what does `.c.s:`, `.s.o:` and `.c.s:` mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Those are [*suffix rules*](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html).  They are a more primitive and limited (but standards conforming) form of pattern rules.

The rule `.c.o` means "if you have a foo.c, you can turn it into a foo.o with this recipe".  Ditto for the others.